# Rails ActionMailer says Route does not exist when it does

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route (from rake routes):

```
reset_password GET /reset_password/:token(.:format) password_resets#edit
```

but when I try and send an email that includes that link I get a

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /forgotten_password
No route matches {}
```

Here is a screenshot from BetterErrors that proves my point:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written link_to twice on line 11.